# Access Request in Service Provider After Applying Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container

## Bindings

I'm using bindings in my service provider between interface and implementation:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('MyInterface', MyImplementation::class);
}
```

## Middleware

In my middleware, I add an attribute to the request:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->attributes->add(['foo' => 'bar]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

## Now, I want to access `foo` in my service provider

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('MyInterface', new MyImplementation($this->request->attributes->get('foo')); // Request is not available
}
```

## The register() is called before applying the middleware. I know.

I'm looking for a technique to 'rebind' if the request->attributes->get('foo') is set

Comment: But isn't this a bad practice in general? Launching SPs is a part of bootstrap process, handling a request happens later. It sounds somewhat awkward - changing the boot process based on request. Shouldn't you solve your problem some other way?

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. But, now, I've to instantiate concrete implementations, which isn't great maintainable.

Comment: Why? You could bind another implementation to the interface in your Middleware, based on $request parameters

Comment: No, no, Denis ;-) The only place I bind is in the Service Provider. But in my case, I need an attribute (added in the middleware) from the request object for my binding (see my register method in my main question)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('MyInterface', function () {
        $request = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);

        return app(MyImplementation::class, [$request->foo]);
    }
}
```

Binding elements works like this that they will be triggered only when they are call.

Comment: Thanks! You mean defered?

Comment: Exactly I mean defered.

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks. But is this a bad practice?

Comment: Absolutely not. This is how IoC container works and it's it one of advantage.

Comment: For those who might wonder `app` refers to the Laravel helper function: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-app

Answer (score 11):

In `service provider` You can also access `Request Object` by:

```
public function register()
{
    $request = $this->app->request;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good, however it does not address the issues regarding DI. So in your Service Provider you need:

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('MyInterface', function () {
        return new MyImplementation(request()->foo);
    }
}
```

But you need to be careful with DI. If you do this in your Controller:

```php
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(MyInterface $myInterface)
    {
        $this->myInterface = $myInterface;
    }
}
```

It will NOT work! The constructor of the controller is called BEFORE the group middleware is applied, so the `foo` parameter will be null on `MyImplementation`.

If you want to use DI, you need to either resolve it using `App::make(MyInterface::class)` outside of the constructor, or even better pass your dependency in the Controller's method:

```php
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index(MyInterface $myInterface)
    {
        $myInterface->getFoo();
    }
}
```

Above will work because the controller's method is executed **after** the middlewares are applied.

This is the flow of a laravel request:

1. Global middleware run
2. Target controller's `__construct` run
3. Group middleware run
4. Target controller's method/action run (in above case `index`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('MyInterface', function ($app) {
        return new MyImplementation(request()->foo);
    }
}
```