# Best Practice Access Request in Service Provider After Applying Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request

I have already found the answer on how to **Access Request in Service Provider After Applying Middleware**

```
$request = app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class);
```

[Access Request in Service Provider After Applying Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555236/access-request-in-service-provider-after-applying-middleware)

[image]

But is this a good practice? is there a better way to access the request body inside **appServiceProvider**?
Thanks.

Comment: At first glance you are probably ok here as you are only giving your implementation the data it needs, and not the request itself(I've done this and it makes testing rather difficult). Although you could probably do a little less typing by using the `request()` helper.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of your service container bindings will be registered within service providers, so most of these examples will demonstrate using the container in that context.

**There is no need to bind classes into the container if they do not depend on any interfaces. The container does not need to be instructed on how to build these objects, since it can automatically resolve these objects using reflection.**

***Simple Bindings***

Within a service provider, you always have access to the container via the `$this->app` property. We can register a binding using the `bind` method, passing the class or interface name that we wish to register along with a `Closure` that returns an instance of the class:

```
$this->app->bind('HelpSpot\API', function ($app) {
    return new HelpSpot\API($app->make('HttpClient'));
});
```

*Note that we receive the container itself as an argument to the resolver. We can then use the container to resolve sub-dependencies of the object we are building.*

***Binding A Singleton***

The singleton method binds a class or interface into the container that should only be resolved one time. Once a singleton binding is resolved, the same object instance will be returned on subsequent calls into the container:

```
$this->app->singleton('HelpSpot\API', function ($app) {
    return new HelpSpot\API($app->make('HttpClient'));
});
```